# Hide div element in browser but print the element using jsPDF

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I am working on jsPDF. I want to hide an element from displaying on browser but it should print as pdf using jsPDF anfd html2canvas.

```
<div>
    id="divToPrint"
    className="mt4"
    style={{
    backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
    width: "210mm",
    minHeight: "297mm",
    marginLeft: "300px",
    marginRight: "300px",
    // visibility: "hidden",
</div>
```